# $\lim_{n\to \infty}(x_n+y_n)$ exist and $\lim_{n\to \infty} y_n$ exist then the $\lim_{n \to \infty }x_n$ exist or not?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If we take two real sequences say $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ with $\{x_n + y_n\}$  and $\{y_n\}$ is convergent. What can we say about the convergence of the sequence  $\{x_n\}$?
My attempt is 
let $\lim_{n\to \infty}(x_n+y_n)=l$ say and  $\lim_{n\to \infty} y_n=m$ say, for $\epsilon\gt 0$ we always choose an integer $k$ such that
$\vert x_n +y_n-l\vert \lt\epsilon$ and $\vert y_n-m\vert \lt \epsilon$ for all $n\geq k$

therefore $\vert x_n - (l-m)\vert =\vert x_n+y_n-y_n-(l-m)\vert \lt 2\epsilon$, therefore $\{x_n\}$ is convergent.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, your attempt is correct. It is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}( (x_n+y_n)-y_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (x_n+y_n)-\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}y_n.$

Comment: Your effort is correct but it is a little tidier to use $|x_n +y_n-l|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|y_n-m|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, so that $|x_n - (l-m)|=|x_n+y_n-y_n-(l-m)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Do you already know that the difference of convergent sequences is also convergent?  If so, just note $x_n=(x_n+y_n)-y_n$.